# MongoDB with spark gives null values in Dataframe

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

I am trying to connect to mongoDB using spark. When I try to read the data from MongoDB by inferring the schema automatically I see all the values.
However I face issues when I try to explicitly specify the schema and when try to see the values in Dataset it gives me nulls.

I am using Java  and created java class to define the schema.

Please could someone help me troubleshoot the issue

> below the code snippet :-

```
    public class MVTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test")
                 .master("local[2]")
         .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost/mongoFocusDump.PositionResultDocuments")
         .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri","mongodb://localhost/mongoFocusDump.PositionResultDocuments").getOrCreate();

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

            Dataset<MongoSchema> df = MongoSpark.load(jsc).toDS(MongoSchema.class);

        df.printSchema();

        df.select("simulationScenario").show();
       jsc.close();
    } 
}
```

> Output :-

```
+------------------+
|simulationScenario|
+------------------+
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
|              null|
+------------------+
```